# How to skip rows in database result without using offset

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table in my DataBase which look like:

| Name | Amount | E ID | UpdateDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | 100 | 6 | 2022-02-14 11:15:13 |
| Michell | 240 | 8 | 2022-01-16 10:12:21 |

This table contains hundreds of thousands of records. I have to write a pagination query which fetch 10 records per page with latest UpdateDate and other conditions. Below is the query I am using:

```
Select Name, Amount, EID
from Employee
where Amount < 150
OrderBy UpdateDate desc
Offset 0 rows Fetch next 10 rows only
```

For first page I am using offset as 0, for second page using Offset as 1, for third page using offset as 2, respectively.
Query is working fine for me, but due to heavy data in table sometimes it took long time due to which Java API throws timeout error (because I have to wait for some 20-30 secs for response).

I doubt pagination with offset causing this timeout issue. Is there a way we can optimize this query or any alternate to this 'offset' condition

Comment: Show us table and index definitions.

Comment: https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/partial-results/fetch-next-page

Comment: Hi @JamesZ, thanks for letting me know

Comment: Hi @jarlh, using the Clustered index on PK , which is EID, also the link you shared I checked earlier , syntatical issue it have like : we cannot have orderby Clause in subqueries  etc...    We can use the Seek approach but the challenge here is I need to perform Order BY on UpdateDate column

Answer (score 0):

"Remember where you left off" instead of using `OFFSET`:  [*Pagination*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination)